# Data Storage in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

i am trying to build a hybrid mobile app using jquery mobile and intel XDK involving a simple listview using jquery mobile that opens into a info page whose content is not likely to change except occasional small change.so i am confused how to design the info page's content whether it should be hardcoded or dynamic. i want it to be available offline.

i cannot use websql or localstorage because its an informative app and the user does not need to add any info.i am confused can i still use the former options or there is any better way? And if i hardcode it, how to notify the user for an update? i need some direction.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you be getting the information from? Database?
If its not going to change then yeah hardcode it - but that means you will need to release new versions of the app when ever there is a change to the data.

Otherwise you can use APIs which will hit the data source, returning the information in the form, JSON which you can loop through and display what you want - this however will need an internet connection..